# Connect to WCF service using ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api

Is there some good tutorial on this subject? I was trying to find something, but there is almost nothing on this subject on the web. Maybe my search criteria is bad. I'm trying to find simple sample on how can I for example connect to some WCF service whos returning some data and get it using WebApi Get method.

Comment: Why do you want to use WCF in Web Api? What is your scenario?

Comment: What is that you are trying to achieve ? Still You can include `WCF` `Proxy` class into your WebApi project and then get the data from WCF and pass onto the next method whoever requested it.

Comment: @UğurAldanmaz I don't have any scenario, that's why I've didn't include some code. I would like to research this topic little bit more, just want to know is this possible and what are the possible ways to do this...:)

Comment: @CoderofCode I'm just trying to learn a little bit more about this... To see what are my possibilities and can I combine this two technologies, and internet resources are pretty much weak on this...So I'm not even sure is it possible to do something like that...

Comment: Ok if you use `Proxy` class of the WCF then it is possible because I have done that way but not sure about if there are other ways.

Comment: @CoderofCode Cool thanks for suggestion I will try to dig it a little bit :)

Answer (score 4):

How you consume a WCF service does not change for ASP.NET Web API, easiest way to invoke a WCF service is by creating a Service reference of it, it can be done:
1) Right click on your WebApi project and choose "Add Service Reference", This would create a reference(Proxy) class and configuration changes in web/app.config.
2) Now, you create an instance of this class, and call the methods exposed by the service.

There are other ways you can invoke a WCF service, one is by creating a proxy class using svcutilexe and including this in your project and follow step (2) or by using [ChannelFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx).

Note: It is a good practice to NOT return WCF objects directly to the client, because any change in the response would also break the consumer of the api, create models for your api , convert WCF response objects to model and return this instead.